# React.js and Styling - Best practice

Tags: javascript, css, reactjs, modularity, react-css-modules

Hopefully this is a question that can help people.

I am really new on React.js and I am still pondering on which approach to have for the styling on my React single page app.

Here are some documentations I read:

Inline:
https://facebook.github.io/react/tips/inline-styles.html

Debate on inline or not (quite old post):
https://css-tricks.com/the-debate-around-do-we-even-need-css-anymore/

or even some interesting modularity such as this one:
https://medium.com/@jviereck/modularise-css-the-react-way-1e817b317b04#.bs7pbqj4j

and finally:
http://reactcss.com/

I am advocating on a .scss file per component, that you can import in your component JS (only) and use there. Sounds like the closest from a modular perspective. However I am unsure if that's the best way for re-usability and scalability over time.

Any inputs and point of view welcome.

Thanks!

Comment: SO is where people come to look for answers to questions and not for expressions of opinion. Please read the FAQ on how to ask questions and what topics are allowed here.

Comment: another option http://fela.js.org/

Comment: Yeah. I'd have to second Rob's comment. You might want to try the React Reddit group or something along those lines. As for my opinion, I'm personally beginning to lean towards using basscss and (almost) eliminating CSS/SCSS from my project altogether. Also, I wrote this: https://github.com/chrisdavies/stylextract-loader